# The getter 'length' was called on null - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to get data from firestore database and this code worked perfectly. But now it's not working and I'm getting this error

> The getter 'length' was called on null.
>
> Receiver: null
>
> Tried calling: length"

this is the code getting error.

```
class MiddleHelpers extends ChangeNotifier {
  Widget datafav(BuildContext context, String collection) {
    return Container(
      height: 280.0,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<ManageData>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchData(collection),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageTransition(
                          child: DetailScreen(
                              queryDocumentSnapshot: snapshot.data[index]),
                          type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            blurRadius: 5,
                            // spreadRadius: 3,
                            offset: Offset(3, 3),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

fetch data method

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ManageData extends ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Future fetchData(String collection) async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).get();
    return querySnapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

error on device

[image]

Comment: Check for `!snapshot.hasData` also at your spinner check.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your snapshot.data is null there may be error . try adding

`if (snapshot.hasError){ return Text('Something went wrong'); }`
inside builder

more info here
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are receiving no data from future and that's why you can't use `.length`. Also, it is necessary to make sure data existence and then use `.length`.

It would be better to introduce all state that can be occurred during `FutureBuilder` process.

Check

- `snapshot.connectionState` if it is `waiting` or `done`. Then
- if `snapshot.hasError`, finally `else` or `hasData`
- if `snapshot.hasData`, also you can check data length>0  or `snapshot.data!.exist` then return `ListView.builder`

I prefer [this example of firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read).

```dart
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

         return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
   ///.............
        }

        return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

More about

- [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)
- [firestore usage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)